# Assign value to pointer

Tags: c

I have code as below :

```
unsigned int* Adc = 0x2000;
```

As my understanding the address of ADC is 0x2000, is it right ?
And if I want to assign value to Adc, i just write like this :

```
Adc = 88;
```

Is it correct or not ?

Comment: No it is not correct, this is not valid C code. You'll want something like `volatile uint16_t* Adc = (volatile uint16_t*)0x2000; .. *Adc = 88;`

Comment: @Lundin the duplicate is backwards actually

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Gah, you are correct. They say one thing in the title then do another. Not a good canonical dupe. Regardless, you can't do it the other way around either, for the same reasons. I'll dig for a better canonical post.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I found no good canonical dupe but this is a very common FAQ. So I ended up writing a Q&A style one myself: [“Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast” issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues). Proof-reading much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

> As my understanding the address of ADC is 0x2000, is it right ?

Almost, `unsigned int* Adc = 0x2000;` initializes  `Adc` with that *value*.   If 0x2000 is not a valid value to assign that pointer, the result is *undefined behavior* (UB), so hopefully there is some system dependent info indicating this is a valid address for an `unsigned` pointer.

The  pointer `Adc` exists someplace in memory at some address. The address of `Adc`  makes little difference to your goal.

To be clear, the pointer `Adc` has a *value* of 0x2000 and `Adc` exist someplace in memory at some *address*.

> Is it correct or not ?

Not quite. `Adc = 88;` assigns a new *value* to the pointer `Adc` from its original `0x2000`.

To change the memory pointed to by `Adc`, de-reference  it: `*Adc = 88;`

Comment: Well `Adc = 88` doesn't assign, because it is a constraint violation... what an implementation would do then is up to the implementation.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Assigning an integer to a pointer is implementation-defined, not a constraint violation.

Comment: @Barmar an integer cannot be converted to a pointer without an explicit cast, except if it is the null pointer constant (same goes for the initialization too).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, Sorry i still not fulyy get it. Between these 2 codes :           unsigned int* Adc = 0x2000;  and                                                                           unsigned int Adc = 0x2000;  The difference is first Adc is Pointer and the second Adc is variable ? But both have same value that 0x2000, Is it Correct?

Comment: @Rambe They are both variables. The first is a pointer to an `unsigned int`, the other is an `unsigned int`. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: @Barmar It is a constraint violation of simple assignment C17 6.5.16.1 §1.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, someone else already clarified that. I was just thinking about the conversion, not the castless syntax.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I understand now, thank you for your explanation.