# "Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast" issues

Tags: c, pointers, casting, initialization, assignment-operator

*This question is meant to be a FAQ entry for all initialization/assignment between integer and pointer issues.*

---

I want to do write code where a pointer is set to a specific memory address, for example `0x12345678`. But when compiling this code with the gcc compiler, I get "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast" warnings/errors:

```
int* p = 0x12345678;
```

Similarly, this code gives "initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast":

```
int* p = ...;
int i =  p;
```

If I do the same outside the line of variable declaration, the message is the same but says "assignment" instead of "initialization":

```
p = 0x12345678; // "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"
i = p;          // "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"
```

Tests with other popular compilers also give error/warning messages:

- clang says "incompatible integer to pointer conversion"
- icc says "a value of type `int` cannot be used to initialize an entity of type `int*`"
- MSVC (cl) says "initializing `int*` differs in levels of indirection from `int`".

**Question: Are the above examples valid C?**

---

And a follow-up question:

This does not give any warnings/errors:

```
int* p = 0;
```

Why not?

Comment: the question could explicitly say that "I want to have a pointer that points to memory address 0x12345678" and then the answer could tackle this

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yeah good call, especially since the answer already hinted of best practices when dealing with memory addresses. I added a new sentence at the top of the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it is not valid C and has never been valid C. These examples are so-called *constraint violations* of the standard.

The standard does not allow you to initialize/assign a pointer to an integer, nor an integer to a pointer. You need to manually force a type conversion with a cast:

```
int* p = (int*) 0x1234;

int i = (int)p;
```

If you don't use the cast, the code is not valid C and your compiler is not allowed to let the code pass without displaying a message. The cast operator states: C17 6.5.4/3:

> **Constraints**
> /--/
> Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be specified by means of an explicit cast.

6.5.16.1 being the rules of *simple assignment* that allow certain implicit conversions of pointers, see C17 6.5.16.1 §1:

> **6.5.16.1 Simple assignment**

> **Constraints**

> One of the following shall hold:
>
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified arithmetic type, and the right has
>   arithmetic type;
> - the left operand has an atomic, qualified, or unqualified version of a structure or union type
>   compatible with the type of the right;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type
>   the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified
>   or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the
>   qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type
>   the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer to an object type,
>   and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, and the type pointed to
>   by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
> - the left operand is an atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer, and the right is a null pointer
>   constant; or
> - the left operand has type atomic, qualified, or unqualified _Bool, and the right is a pointer.

In case of `int* p = 0x12345678;`, the left operand is a pointer and the right is an arithmetic type.
In case of `int i = p;`, the left operand is an arithmetic type and the right is a pointer.
Neither of these fit in with any of the constraints cited above.

As for why `int* p = 0;` works, it is a special case. The left operand is a pointer and the right is a *null pointer constant*. [More info about the difference between null pointers, null pointer constants and the NULL macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32136460/584518).

---

Some things of note:

- If you assign a raw address to a pointer, the pointer likely needs to be `volatile` qualified, given that it points at something like a hardware register or an EEPROM/Flash memory location, that can change its contents in run-time.
- Converting a pointer to an integer is by no means guaranteed to work even with the cast. The standard (C17 6.3.2.3 §5 and §6 says):

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
> result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
> entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation. <sup>68)</sup>

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result
> is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is
> undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.

Informative foot note:

> <sup>68)</sup> The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment.

In addition, the address from a pointer might be larger than what will fit inside an `int`, as is the case for most 64 bit systems. Therefore it is better to use the `uintptr_t` from `<stdint.h>`

Comment: You could add sth about the footnote 67) of C11: *The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment.* I.e. a quality implementation wouldn't just pull the numbers from hat ;)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Added the foot note. And yeah pre-ANSI tended to treat all types as `int`. Regardless, it has never been standardized. More worrying is that some semi-modern embedded systems compilers let this kind of code through without any diagnostic messages. IIRC, some older PC compilers like Borland did this too.

Comment: So `p = 0x10000000;` would be OK (not a constrain violation) iff `0x10000000` happened to be another implementation specific  _null pointer constant_?

Comment: *"An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant."*; you could add that, from http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3

Comment: @chux A _null pointer_ may have the binary representation 0x1234.... whatever, but a _null pointer constant_ is either `0` or `(void*)0`. See the posted link in the answer.

Comment: The spec allows `0u`, `0L`, `(void*) 0LL` as a _null pointer constant_, not only `0` as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues/52186835?noredirect=1#comment91326855_52186835).  Also the spec does not clearly disallow other forms of a _null pointer constant_ - the crux of the question on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues/52186835?noredirect=1#comment91324362_52186835)

Comment: The standard calls ICE with value 0 or such cast to `(void*)` as a null pointer constant. How do you read that other values that are not `== 0` are permissible? Then the entire standard is is void because you can add anything after a list that contains `or`?!

Comment: I believe the implementation-defined value of `NULL` in the standard refers to a compiler either using `0` or `(void*)0` as the NULL macro.

Comment: Well it can use `0LL` for sure, or `0ULL` or `'\0'` or `(5-5)`. But not `42`. As `42` is not what the standard calls a null pointer constant.

Comment: "How do you read that other values that are not == 0 are permissible?" --> Had the spec been: "a _null pointer constant_ is an integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *" (A is defined only from B or b), I would readily agree with the limited possibilities you suggest.  Yet the spec is the other way around (B or b leads to A). As I read that, other forms of _null pointer constant_ are possible, even if not common in practice (C may lead to A).  Thanks for your insights.

Comment: I am not saying you are correct or incorrect as much as wondering about the possible interpretations of the C spec.  Your assertion is reasonable and certainly true in practice - which the later point tends to win the day when divining ambiguity.

Comment: @chux From the C99 rationale 7.17: "NULL can be defined as any null pointer constant. Thus existing code can retain definitions of
NULL as 0 or 0L, but an implementation may also choose to define it as (void*)0. This latter
form of definition is convenient on architectures where sizeof(void*) does not equal the
size of any integer type."