# What is the difference between (char*)'r' and "r"?

Tags: c, char

I'm confused at the differences between `(char*)'r'` and `"r"`, and perhaps `(char*)"r"`, if that's different from `"r"`.

```
int main () {
    char fileNameOriginal[MAXLINE] = "test.txt";
    openFile(&fp, fileNameOriginal, (char*)'r');
}
openFile(FILE **fp, char fileName[], char* mode) {
    *fp = fopen(fileName, mode);
}
```

This format for passing the mode argument of `fopen` will not cause a warning/error by my eclipse IDE. However, the file will not be read correctly. On the other hand, passing `"r"` or `(char*)"r"` will generate a correct reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(char*)'r'` is a an attempt to convert the `int` constant `'r'` to a `char*` pointer. That actual value associated with `'r'` depends on the *encoding* your system uses.

When the library function attempts to *dereference* that pointer, the program behaviour will be *undefined*.

`"r"` on the other hand is a `char[2]` type, which will *decay* to a `char*` pointer required by the function.

It's difficult for an IDE to issue a warning for the incorrect case; and remember that one of the tenets of C is that you are assumed that you know what you're doing!

Comment: No, that's fine in C, although you do need the explicit cast. @Lundin has an excellent FAQ on this.

Comment: `(char*)'r'` might cause UB  (it's implementation-defined and could be misaligned and/or a trap respresentation

Comment: On the FAQ, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues/52186835#52186835

Comment: ...which agrees with what I just said

Comment: @M.M Do you agree that `(int*)'r'` is safe? (Indeed your knowledge is better than mine on these issues.)

Comment: @Bathsheba no, it might cause UB (it's implementation-defined and could be misaligned and/or a trap respresentation -- as explained by the page you linked)

Comment: Although the `(char *)` version wouldn't be misaligned (char has alignment 1), it could still be a trap

Comment: Thanks for the help you two, as well as the FAQ.

Answer (score 4):

In C all character literals are really `int` values. For systems using the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding system (the vast majority) then `'r'` is equal to `114`.

So your call is really `openFile(&fp, fileNameOriginal, (char*)114);`, and even a beginner should see that it's not really correct.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense yea.