# Why main runs with return type string even though it is defined with a integer return type?

Tags: c, function

The code is compiling evan though the main has a return type of **int** it works with the return type string without and errors what is the reason behind it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    printf("Hello World");
    //if(i!=0)
       return "hai";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't compile: https://ideone.com/nUfAEo

Comment: i compiled it and it works @UnholySheep

Comment: `"hai"` returns a `const char*`, which can be casted to `int`. I would assume that it requires an explicit cast in c++ at least, though.

Comment: Enable warnings and the compiler should complain.

Comment: It compiles in C, but not without warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/fIQzVv

Comment: Also note that the behavior is most likely different in C and C++, because they are two very different languages. For future questions please don't mix language tags like that.

Comment: In C, for any other function than `main` the compiler would issue a warning like "C4047: 'return': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [4]'". But `main` has different rules for its return.

Comment: Please remove the c++ tag since it doesn't compile with c++ and you are using a c compiler.

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes you right, but i expected a error for difference in datatype that's y raised a question. anyways thanks for the response

Comment: ok @ThomasSablik will do that

Comment: Do it in a user defined function and it won't work. In main it is implied, it works even if you don't return 0;

Comment: @Blaze: "hai" has type `char[4]` and converts to `char*` in the context of the `return` statement, with no `const`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I keep forgetting about that.

Comment: @aschleper : it's not (necessarily) valid in C. Converting a pointer to an integer type has implementation defined behavior. It might even have undefined behavior (if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the integer type).

Comment: This is not valid C at all. There is no implicit cast from `char *` to `int`. It is a constraints violation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast” issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues).

Comment: And if you want to block invalid C code from compiling in gcc, you must compile with `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Lundin

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Ah, I see. Deleting my comment that this is valid C.  (I was thrown off by the fact that Standard section 6.3 "Conversions" doesn't mention many differences between explicit and implicit conversions. Instead, the restrictions on implicit conversions are listed in 6.5.16.1 about the `=` operator, and other implicit conversions like for parameters of a function with prototype and for return values are done "as if by assignment".)

Comment: @aschepler exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## C

You do not return the string or pointer, only the pointer casted to integer. And Compiler will warn you that you have converted the pointer without the explicit cast.

## C++

this code will not compile as C++ does not allow this kind of implicit casts.

Comment: C++ does allow implicit conversions. Just not this particular one.

Comment: @aschepler I think this question is only C. Beginners tend to put both languages in the tags

Comment: If answering for C++, I would add that C++ would accept this if the cast is explicit (i.e. `return (long)"hai";`)

Comment: @P__J__ "I think this question is only C." => So why did you answer for C++ ?

Comment: @Stargateur because there is a `C++` tag there. Logical I think

Comment: Neither C nor C++ allow implicit conversions from `char*` to `int`. This code has never been valid in either language. Therefore this answer is misleading. "It compiles" is not a term enforced by the languages, they only enforce diagnostic messages. If you wish to prevent non-standard-C from compiling with gcc, you must use `-pedantic-errors`. Which doesn't mean "give me pedantic errors" but rather "give me an error if I write invalid C code".

Comment: @Lundin did I write that it is a valid code? If no your long elaborate is completely useless. BTW converions from pointers to integer types are common in the uC programming, and the code is valid of cohrse5

Comment: My point is that C and C++ behave exactly identically here, so there is no need to make a distinction between the languages. The only difference is with the default settings of the gcc compiler + the gcc wannabe compilers (clang, icc), all of them producing a warning instead of an error. Wheras other C compilers, as well as C++ compilers, produce an error when they find this constraint violation of the simple assignment rule. This is no fault of the C language.

Answer (score 7):

The program is an **invalid** C program. `"hai"` has type `char [4]` and in the context of return statement it decays to `char *`.

However the function needs to return `int`. In the context of `return` this happens if by assignment.

A `char *` can be converted to `int` but it requires an explicit cast. In absence of an explicit cast, it is a constraint violation and a compiler **must** produce a diagnostics message, which `gcc` does:

```
warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    return "hai";
           ^~~~~
```

---

Finally: the C standard mentions in a [footnote](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note9):

> [a conforming implementation] may also successfully translate an invalid program.