# Why returning NULL from main()?

Tags: c++, c, null, return, return-value

I sometimes see coders that use `NULL` as return value of `main()` in C and C++ programs, for example something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("HelloWorld!");

    return NULL;
}
```

---

When I compile this `code with gcc I get the warning of:

> warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

which is reasonable because the macro `NULL` shall be expanded to `(void*) 0` and the return value of main shall be of type `int`.

When I make a short C++ program of:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "HelloWorld!";

    return NULL;
}
```

And compile it with g++, I do get an equivalent warning:

> warning: converting to non-pointer type ‘int’ from NULL [-Wconversion-null]

But why do they use `NULL` as return value of `main()` when it throws a warning? Is it just bad coding style?

---

- What is the reason to use `NULL` instead of `0` as return value of `main()` despite the warning?
- Is it implementation-defined if this is appropriate or not and if so why shall any implementation would want to get a pointer value back?

Comment: You should ask them directly.

Comment: "why do they use NULL as return value of main()" - we don't. The author of that code does. I'd be interested in hearing *their* attempt at justifying why.

Comment: @juanchopanza I´ve already asked one, he said: "I´ve seen it anywhere else."

Comment: @kiranBiradar What is EXIT_SUCCESS?

Comment: `The value of EXIT_SUCCESS is defined in stdlib.h as 0` says the [doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.bpxbd00/exit.htm)

Comment: @WhozCraig I´ve said "they" - meaning the ones who code in this way. I did not suppose that everyone does it that way, which is definitely not the case. I´ve already asked one, he said: "I´ve seen it anywhere else."

Comment: @Waelmio And moreover EXIT_SUCCESS is a macro.:)

Comment: @Waelmio That's IBM's implementation. The actual value of EXIT_SUCCESS is implementation-defined. Its one reason why the standard calls out that *either* EXIT_SUCCESS *or* zero are valid success indicators on program exit. (7.22.4.4)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow yes but I had to check if it was really 0. ^^ - `EXIT_FAILURE` is 8, and it seems using 1 is not good for a failure since it's sometime used as a success in some programs.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio if that was really the response you got, that's kind of sad. First, it doesn't make sense (would make more sense if it were *everywhere* rather than *anywhere*). Second, it is a sell out. If you're writing code, you'd better have a good compass on whether it is correct; not just go with it because that's the way it seems to be done by... someone. You seem to have that needle pointing the right direction (thus why you're asking); not so much the person that wrote that code, then fed you that answer as the reason why.

Comment: In c, it is perfectly valid to define the `NULL` pointer as `0` (without a cast to `void *`). In this case, the flaw goes unnoticed and does not generate a warning. It still is not what NULL should be used for.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, agree. But I´d just want to ask if there is any reason to code in this weird kind of way, I may have missed. But it seems that it isn´t and I´m glad that it is so. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've been coding for quite a while.  I've never seen any code that used `return NULL;` in main.    "_Is it just bad coding style?_"  Yes, very.

Comment: @machine_1 My intention is not to blame anyone specifically, especially because this is such a deprecated coding style (assuming it is valid/ warnings keep warnings, not migrate to errors by relative compiler flags). I think, it is just because of pure confusion based on the wrong assumption that `NULL` shall be equivalent to the integral value of `0` which isn´t the case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> which is reasonable

Yes.

> because the macro `NULL` shall be expanded to `(void*) 0`

No. In C++ the macro `NULL` *must not* expand to `(void*) 0` [support.types.nullptr]. It may only do so in C.

Either way, writing code like this is misleading since `NULL` is supposed to refer to the *null pointer constant*, regardless of how it’s implemented. Using it in place of an `int` is a logical error.

> - What is the reason to use `NULL` instead of 0 as return value of `main()` despite the warning?

Ignorance. There is no *good* reason to do this.

> - Is it implementation-defined if this is appropriate or not and if so why shall any implementation would want to get a pointer value back?

No, it is never *appropriate*. It is up to the implementation whether the compiler *allows* it. A conforming C++ compiler may well allow it without warning.

Comment: My usual thump: it is not **implementaiton-defined** whether the compiler allows it; it is **implemenation-specific**. In the standard, "implemenation-defined" means that the implementation must document what it does.

Comment: @PeteBecker I did pause when writing it but went ahead anyway (because  “implementation-specific” and similar phrases just sound unnatural). But you’re correct, I’ll change it.

Comment: Seems to me that the only reason "implementation-defined" sounds natural is that people are used to seeing it misused. <g>

Answer (score 8):

> When I compile this `code with gcc I get the warning of:
>
> ```
> warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
> ```

This is because you compile with lax compiler options. Use strict C standard settings `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors` and you will get the expected compiler error, on implementations where `NULL` expands to the null pointer constant `(void*)0`. See [“Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast” issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues).

On implementations where `NULL` expands to `0`, the code is strictly speaking standard compliant, but very bad style, non-portable and worst of all: complete nonsense.

> And compile it with g++, I do get an equivalent warning:
>
> ```
> warning: converting to non-pointer type ‘int’ from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
> ```

On C++11 and beyond, `NULL` shouldn't be used - instead use `nullptr`. To return it from main() is incorrect regardless. `NULL` always expands to `0` in C++ so strictly speaking it will work, but it is very bad style and worst of all: complete nonsense.

> Is it just bad coding style?

Not just bad, but nonsense coding style without any rationale. The programmer who wrote it was incompetent.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it just bad coding style?

Worse. The correct way to indicate that the program finished fine is

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: That's pure pedantry. According to the C standard, a 0 argument to `exit()` (or a 0 return value from main) means the same as `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

Comment: And since c99 you can just omit the `return` from `main`. So, a more "correct" version of your program is `int main(void){}` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In ?some/many/all? C++ implementations `NULL` is a macro expanded to `0`.

This when expanded in effect gives `return 0`. Which is a valid return value.

> Is it just bad coding style?

Yes.