# Fix gcc warnings with _Generic macro and compound literals

Tags: c, generics, gcc, gcc-warning, compound-literals

I have a struct with a union and an enum of its kind in it. I've made a macro that outputs a compound literal of the struct, that sets the kind and the data of the union according to the type passed to the macro use _Generic.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct mystruct {
    enum { K_NUM, K_STR } kind;
    union { int num; char * str; };
};

#define MYSTRUCT(X) _Generic((X), \
    int: (struct mystruct){K_NUM, .num=X}, \
    char *: (struct mystruct){K_STR, .str=X} \
)

void print_mystruct(struct mystruct s) {
    switch (s.kind) {
    case K_NUM: printf("mystruct (num): %d\n", s.num); break;
    case K_STR: printf("mystruct (str): %s\n", s.str); break;
    }
}

int main() {
    print_mystruct(MYSTRUCT(2));
    print_mystruct(MYSTRUCT("test"));
}
```

It does compile with gcc, and then running it correctly outputs:

```
mystruct (num): 2
mystruct (str): test
```

But I get all these compile warnings:

```
c.c: In function 'main':
c.c:21:26: warning: initialization of 'char *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   21 |  print_mystruct(MYSTRUCT(2));
      |                          ^
c.c:10:40: note: in definition of macro 'MYSTRUCT'
   10 |  char *: (struct mystruct){K_STR, .str=X} \
      |                                        ^
c.c:21:26: note: (near initialization for '(anonymous).<anonymous>.str')
   21 |  print_mystruct(MYSTRUCT(2));
      |                          ^
c.c:10:40: note: in definition of macro 'MYSTRUCT'
   10 |  char *: (struct mystruct){K_STR, .str=X} \
      |                                        ^
c.c:22:26: warning: initialization of 'int' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   22 |  print_mystruct(MYSTRUCT("test"));
      |                          ^~~~~~
c.c:9:37: note: in definition of macro 'MYSTRUCT'
    9 |  int: (struct mystruct){K_NUM, .num=X}, \
      |                                     ^
c.c:22:26: note: (near initialization for '(anonymous).<anonymous>.num')
   22 |  print_mystruct(MYSTRUCT("test"));
      |                          ^~~~~~
c.c:9:37: note: in definition of macro 'MYSTRUCT'
    9 |  int: (struct mystruct){K_NUM, .num=X}, \
      |                                     ^
```

I tried casts in the compound literals like so:

```
int: (struct mystruct){K_NUM, .num=(int)X}, \
char *: (struct mystruct){K_STR, .str=(char *)X} \
```

But I get different warnings:

```
c.c: In function 'main':
c.c:9:37: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
    9 |  int: (struct mystruct){K_NUM, .num=(int)X}, \
      |                                     ^
c.c:22:17: note: in expansion of macro 'MYSTRUCT'
   22 |  print_mystruct(MYSTRUCT("test"));
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `(int)X` --> `(int)(intptr_t)(X)` to quiet [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]

Answer (score 2):

This is because each time you call the macro, all cases where the macro parameter `X` is 
found are expanded. So when you pass `2`, you get

```
_Generic(2, int: (struct mystruct){K_NUM, .num=2}, char *: (struct mystruct){K_STR, .str=2}
```

And even though the `char*` case is not executed, it is still compiled and assigning an integer to a string `.str=2` isn't valid C.

Consider taking a different approach entirely. Leave the macro argument outside of the _Generic list, for example. And do you even need the enum since the types are known at compile-time?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_int (int x) { printf("%d\n", x); }
void print_str (const char* x) { puts(x); }

#define print(x) _Generic((x), \
  int:    print_int,           \
  char*:  print_str ) (x)

int main(void) 
{
  print(2);
  print("test");
}
```

Comment: `.str=2` is valid C - kinda.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica No. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues

Comment: Interesting "compiler is not allowed to let the code pass without displaying a message." --> so code may pass and compile with a message.  I had expected constraint violations to prevent compilation.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica "Compilation" is not really a concept in standard C, nor is compiler errors. The standard just speaks of "the implementation" and how it must display a "diagnostic message". If "the implementation" displays a message and then chose to produce a binary with random behavior despite that, it is still standard compliant.