# How to do pointer arithmetic if the pointer is in a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Say I have

```
  typedef struct exampleFooStruct foo; 
  typedef char* byte_ptr;

  struct exampleFooStruct{
     byte_ptr p;
     uint32_t num;
  }

  // ...

  foo* one =  malloc(sizeof(foo));
  one->p = 0x5;
  one->num = 0x4;
```

First of all, does one->p assign the value at one->p to be 0x5 or is it setting the address itself to 0x5?

I ultimately want to set the address itself to be 0x5, not the value at that address.

And if I want an `int answer = 0x9`, would I do

```
int answer = one->p + one->num;
//or
int answer = &(one->p) + one->num;
```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it now. It's just a char pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo* one =  malloc(sizeof(foo));
```

This allocates space for a structure object of type `foo` and assigns its address to `one`. This is actually better written as:

```
foo *one = malloc(sizeof *one);`
```

By not repeating the type name, you avoid possible errors if the type of the pointer ever changes.

Note that at this point the value of `one->p` is garbage.

```
one->p = 0x5;
```

This is actually a *constraint violation*. Practically speaking, you should assume that it's illegal. `one->p` is a pointer, and `0x5` is a value of type `int`. There is no implicit conversion from integers to pointers (other than the special case of a null pointer constant, which doesn't apply here).

Your compiler should have at least warned you about this. In fact, any conforming C compiler is required to issue a diagnostic message. (It is, in my opinion, unfortunate that many compilers treat this as a warning rather than a fatal error by default, but there are historical reasons for that).

You could make it legal by doing a cast:

```
one->p = (byte_ptr)0x05;
```

That would store in the pointer object `one->p` the result of converting the integer value 5 to a pointer value.

Unless you're doing some kind of low-level embedded programming on a system where you know what's at that specific memory address, it almost certainly doesn't make sense to do that. `0x05`, even after conversion, is unlikely to be a valid pointer value, and any attempt to use it is likely to crash your program -- if you're lucky. (If you're unlucky it will appear to "work".)

> I ultimately want to set the address itself to be 0x5, not the value at that address.

If that's really what you want to do, then `one->p = (byte_ptr)0x05;` is the way to do it. Why do you want to do that? What is at location 0x05 in memory?

```
int answer = one->p + one->num;
```

`one->p` is a pointer, and `one->num` is an integer. You can add a pointer and an integer, but the result is a pointer, and you can't assign it to an `int` object without a cast. And with a cast, it very likely doesn't make sense.

If you want to store integer values, store them in integer objects.

(If you wanted to store `0x05` in the object that `one->p` points to, you'd first have to arrange for it to point to something, perhaps with another call to `malloc`. But that's not what you asked about, I won't go into that. Perhaps it's what you *should* have asked about, but I'd rather not make any assumptions.)

> And if I want an int answer = 0x9, ...

Then you can write `int answer = 0x9;`. I assume that's not what you're looking for, but I can't tell just what that is.

Finally, what is it you're trying to accomplish? Could it be that you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: It is a project on heap allocation.

Comment: @BlockoButter That doesn't tell me why you want a pointer to memory address `0x05`.

Comment: I tried to pull a number out of thin air, which I learned confused everyone. 0x05 would be 0xF9284D21 or a variable, but out of abstraction, I just put 0x05. Learned my lesson, so next time I post a question, I'm going to try to simulate true form of things to give context to it. In true form, 0x05 would be a pointer to a heap and the integer num would be an offset number of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

> oes one->p assign the value at one->p to be 0x5 or is it setting the address itself to 0x5

assuming `byte_ptr` is indeed a pointer (address), it will do what you probably expect and it will set the pointer to point to address 0x5

> And if I want an int answer = 0x9, would I do
>   you need to tell the compiler to treat the pointer as an integer. it will set answer to 0x9, but this program does not makes sense in my view.:
>       int answer = (int)(one->p) + one->num;

Comment: So I wouldn't need to use the & operation at all? If I do  *(one->p), doesn't that return the value that p is pointing to, not the address itself (which is what I want.)

Comment: probably not. I recommend you to read about pointers, deference and & operator.

Comment: Why don't you run your code, preferrably in a debugger? You'll be able to see the answers for yourself.

Comment: @Inian the pointer itself was allocated as part of the malloc that allocated the whole "one" structure.

Answer (score 1):

The root of all your problems is likely that you hide a pointer behind a typedef, which makes the code very confusing for everyone, including yourself. Please never do that.

> First of all, does one->p assign the value at one->p to be 0x5 or is it setting the address itself to 0x5?

It generates a compiler message since the code isn't valid C. See ["Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast" issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues).

> I ultimately want to set the address itself to be 0x5, not the value at that address.

Then you need to cast: `one->p = (byte_ptr)0x5;`. But this is major code smell, even if the address `5` is valid for your system. Using `char` to access raw data is always wrong, to begin with, since it's a type with impl.defined signedness. And if you want to access physical memory directly, you almost certainly need to use a `volatile` qualifier.

> if I want an int answer = 0x9, would I do

None of your alternatives. The first uses pointer arithmetic, the latter as well, but based on the address of the pointer itself. None make sense.

You'd do `int answer = (uintptr_t)one->p + one->num;`.

---

Overall, consider changing the code to this:

```
  typedef struct {
     uint8_t* p;
     uint32_t num;
  } foo;

  // ...

  foo* one =  malloc(sizeof *one);
  one->p = (volatile uint8_t*)0x5;
  one->num = 0x4;

  uint32_t answer = (uintptr_t)one->p + one->num;
```