# Macro to initialize a CRect causes error C7555:

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to initialize a CRect via a macro so I can use x,y coordinates and getting  C7555 error in VS2022 MFC. What have I missed please? BTW y,cy are inverted!

```
#define SETMYRECT( x , y , cx , cy ) { .left = x  , .top = y , .right = cx , .bottom = cy };
CRect ARect;
ARect = SETMYRECT( 0 , 0 , 50 , 50 );
```

Many thanks in advance imk

Comment: Can't you type `ARect = CRect{ 0 , 0 , 50 , 50 };` instead?

Comment: Designated initializers are a C++20 feature. Do you compile with that version? Also why the double semicolon?

Comment: True i don't need the other semicolon was just testing it out.
Not sure what C++ compiler version used by VS2020, but was a solution i found here and though it my work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360478/using-define-macro-to-initialize-structure-object-in-c

Answer (score 3):

The error [C7555](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-errors-c7500-through-c7999) expands to:

> error C7555: use of designated initializers requires at least '/std:c++20'

The *Windows Desktop Wizard* in Visual Studio 2022 defaults to C++14, so you'll have to change that to C++20 if you wish to take advantage of this language feature. To do so from the IDE, right-click the project, select *Properties*, and navigate to *Configuration Properties* -> *General*. You'll want to set *C++ Language Standard* to *ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20)*.

With that change out of the way, the code compiles as desired.

Not that that's a good thing. There's literally no reason to introduce a preprocessor macro here at all. If you do need to construct a `RECT` (or `CRect`) from `x`, `y`, `cx`, and `cy`, just use a function. And if you do, at least make it work for *any* `x` and `y` (not just 0):

```cpp
inline CRect make_rect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    return CRect{ x, y, x + width, y + height };
}
```

Or just use the appropriate [`CRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/crect-class) constructor:

```cpp
inline CRect make_rect(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    return CRect{ POINT{ x, y }, SIZE{ width, height } };
}
```