# Struct to uint8 Casting

Tags: c, struct, casting

I have a serial port which transmit 256 Byte data over SCI protocol.

The frame has following format:

```
  typedef struct
  {
     int header;
     uint8 ssap;
     uint8 dsap;
     uint8 data[248];
  }Frame;
```

And have following  function

```
  void sciSendStream(int length, uint8* data);
```

My question is how to convert  `Frame` struct to `uint8 *`

When i try to do that with the following cast:

```
  sciSendStream(256,(uint8 *)frame);
```

I am receiving the incompatible conversion error.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Doh!

Comment: What is "SCI protocol"? The only SCI I know of is Motorola's  name for UART hardware.

Comment: `void sciSendStream(int length, uint8* data);` should have  `int sciSendStream(const size_t length, const void *data);` prototype if it was written by sane programmer.

Comment: @Lundin Yes It is a kind of UART protocol

Comment: @Nazim you need to learn pointers and how to use them: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland since this is a legacy code which i cannot modify the parameters was defined with const specifier. Refactoring needed thanks

Comment: @Nazim I can only imagine how bad this code is inside judging only form the prototype :)

Comment: No it is not a _protocol_, it is a piece of hardware sitting in your MCU.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland Tutorialspoint is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62816217/are-the-c-mock-tests-at-tutorialspoint-correct). It's all written by some random student.

Comment: @Lundin still good enough for someone who never heard about pointers\

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland I'd rather recommend newbies to read a book written by someone with actual domain expertise. [Modern C](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) is a decent one and available for free.

Comment: @Lundin thank you very much for your suggestion sir and positive critics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot convert `frame` into `uint8*` because `frame` is not a pointer but a `Frame`. But you can convert the *address* of `frame` (which is a pointer) to a `uint8*` by using the `&` operator.

Just replace:

```
sciSendStream(256, (uint8*)frame);
```

with:

```
sciSendStream(256, (uint8*)&frame);`.
```

I assume `unint8` is `unsigned char`.

Comment: the very first member of `Frame` is `int`, so you are casting `int` to `uint8`. Is this intended / legal?

Comment: well better `sciSendStream(sizeof(Frame), (uint8*)&frame);`

Comment: @StephanLechner, actually it's just casting a pointer to another type of pointer which is perfectly legal.

Comment: @StefanRiedel maybe, but only the OP knows this exactly.

Comment: If we use the non-dysfunctional `uint8_t` instead of home made `uint8`, the code is fine. `uint8_t` will be a character type on all known systems, and can therefore be used to iterate through any form of data. What `uint8` is however, is anyone's guess.

Comment: @Lundin I would rather suggest `const void *`, and `const size_t` for length. The function should also return some status :).

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland The advantage with `const uint8_t*` over `const void*` is type safety. And you can use pointer arithmetic on `const uint8_t*`, meaning it can be treated like an array.

Comment: @Lundin what type safety pointer converison from void * and to void * is safe

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland It's not the actual pointer conversion, it is when you de-reference whatever the void pointer points at. Then you instantly get all manner of concerns about size, alignment, pointer aliasing, trap representations etc etc.

Comment: @Lundin pointer -> void pointe -> pointer to char is same safe as uint8_t pointer.