# correct syntax for giving a pointer

Tags: embedded, stm32

I want to assign a pointer to a memory space to another register, like

```
DMA1_Channel4->CPAR = (uint32_t*)I2C2->TXDR;
```

elsewhere in my code i have used for example

```
DMA1_Channel4->CMAR  = (uint8_t*)DACdata;
```

which works, but gives a warning - assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast. however I don't know the correct syntax for the first instance

Comment: "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" means that you have to actually assign a pointer to an address, not to a value. Missing `&`. But in case a DMA register needs to store the address, you should be casting the address to an integer type, not a pointer type.

Comment: General info: [“Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast” issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPAR field of the DMA1_Channel4 structure most likely expects a value of type `uint32_t`, but you provide a value of type "pointer to `uint32_t`". Most likely you mean:

```
DMA1_Channel4->CPAR = (uint32_t)(&(I2C2->TXDR));
```

Note that I've added a "&" here, as you most likely want to put the address of the TXDR register of the second I2C bus into the CPAR field and not the current value itself.