# Invalid initializer when calling malloc in C?

Tags: c, malloc

I keep getting an invalid initializer error in this line:

```
StackObject_t new = (StackObject_t*)malloc(sizeof(StackObject_t));
```

The StackObject_t type is defined as such:

```
typedef struct stackObject* pStackObject_t;
typedef struct stackObject
{
    void* obj;
    pStackObject_t next;
} StackObject_t;
```

and this is the exact error I get:
[image: Error message]

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: You're assigning a pointer to a thing (`StackObject_t *`) to a thing (`StackObject_t`). Also, recommend not using the variable name `new` because this is a reserved word in C++. This is fully legal in C, but it's a good habit to avoid C++ keywords just to make life easier if/when you step up to C++

Comment: @SteveFriedl Don't be so pessimistic. Not every C programmer has to step down to C++.

Comment: Using `new` as identifier is a good way to get a warning if you accidentally put it in a C++ compiler.

Comment: None the less, syntax formatting IDEs tend to not make a difference between C and C++, as we can see from this SO post. So that alone is a good reason to avoid C++ keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, [you should not cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/5923139) as it can hide errors and C automatically casts `void*` to the correct pointer type. Secondly, your issue is because you have `StackObject_t` as the type of the variable but malloc returns a `StackObject_t*`. You can fix this by changing your line to `StackObject_t* new = ...` so the types match up.

Comment: `malloc` returns a `void *`, not `StackObject_t*`. Also, C automatically **converts** `void *` to other pointer types. It is a conversion, which is an operation that is performed. It is not a **cast**, which is an explicit operator in source code.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for the same reason as `int* ptr; int i = ptr;` doesn't work. A pointer is not a valid initializer to an `int`.

The clang compiler gives a better diagnostic:

> warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'StackObject_t' with an expression of type 'StackObject_t *'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]

Aha, `StackObject_t` is not compatible with `StackObject_t *`. You probably meant to write:

```
StackObject_t* ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
```

Details: ["Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast" issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues)