# GCC warning: initialization of 'int32_t *' {aka 'int *'} from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c, pointers, gcc-warning

Here is a C program:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>


int main() {
    int32_t *ptr = 5;
    printf("ptr is %p\n", ptr);
    printf("++ptr is %p\n", ++ptr);
}
```

The intention is to initialize a pointer with literal address (e. g. `5`) and look how it changes after increment.

`gcc` produces following warning

```
warning: initialization of 'int32_t *' {aka 'int *'} from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    6 |     int32_t *ptr = 5;
      |                    ^
```

**What is the general way to avoid this warning?**

Is "cast" word used as synonym for "explicit cast", so the intended fix is as following?

```c
int32_t *ptr = (int32_t *)5;
```

Or maybe is there a special syntax for pointer literals?

---

For the purpose of the program it's possible to declare an additional variable to initialize pointer with its address (like `int32_t x, *ptr = &x`) or even leave pointer uninitialized, but the question is about this specific warning and initializing pointers with literal values.

Comment: there's no porttable way to initialize pointers with literal addresses except 0. Somtimes I've seen things like `T *ptr = (T *)1;` if you need another special value besides `NULL` but  I doubt that this is covered by the standard. And doing pointer arithmetics when the pointer isn't poperly initialized always invokes Undefined Behaviour

Comment: What is "properly initialized pointer" and how does it differ from "improperly initialized pointer"? Does "improperly initialized pointer" differ from "uninitialized pointer"?

Comment: how about this `int *p;   p = (void* )5;`

Comment: Duplicate: [“Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast” issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues).

Comment: "Is "cast" word used as synonym for "explicit cast"" Casts are always explicit. A cast is an explicit _conversion_ done by the programmer. As opposed by implicit conversions that are done by the C language compiler.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for explanation; I used to interpret "cast" and "conversion" as synonyms. Your explanation answers my question, because this means that warning unambiguously says about lack of *explicit conversion*

Answer (score 1):

You can silence the warning with an explicit cast as you've shown:

```
int32_t *ptr = (int32_t *)5;
```

However, the address 5 is most likely not one your process is allowed to write to and would invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and would most likely crash.