# Why dereferencing after casting void pointer to pointer to char pointer makes problem?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, dereference

I've learned pointer to pointer.
I am curious about dereferencing after casting "integer to pointer" `(char*)(int)` and "void pointer to pointer to char pointer." `(char**)(void*)`

Now there are some issues when I want to dereference to void pointer to pointer to char pointer.`(char**)(void*)`

I tried 2 cases.

integer to pointer `(char*)(int)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
    
    int a = 10;
    int b;
    void* ptr = &a;

    b = ptr;
    printf("%d\n", *(unsigned int*)b);
    printf("%d\n", *(void**)(b));
    printf("%p\n", *(char**)(b));

    return 0;
}

*(unsigned int*)b 
*(void**)(b)
*(char**)(b)**
```

These three read **10** which is in address.

But the code below is *problem*. (Please watch *ptr_speacial*)
"void pointer to pointer to char pointer." `(char**)(void*)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    
    int arr[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    char arr2[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    

    void* ptr_arr;
    void* ptr_arr2;

    void* ptr_special;

    ptr_arr = arr;
    ptr_arr2 = arr2;

    ptr_special = (char*)ptr_arr2 + 4;


    printf("address : %p: value : %d\n", ptr_special, *(char**)ptr_special);
    printf("%d\n", *(char**)ptr_arr);

    return 0;
}
```

`*(char**)ptr_special` did not read 5 which is in address but -858993659

I'm not sure but I think this is overflow problem. What happend in this case? Please help me!

Comment: Most of this code is a problem.  Firstly, you cannot rely on `int` being large enough to store a pointer type.  This is why `intptr_t` exists.  Secondly, you cannot interpret an array type as a `char**`.  It simply is _not_ unless the underlying array actually stores `char*` values.  What you've done with `*(char**)ptr_special` is forced the compiler to treat the memory at `arr2+4` as if it contains a `char*` value, and then you tell `printf` to output that pointer value as a `int` -- also problematic, and is why the `%p` format specifier exists.  Yes, it also overflows, which doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I knew this casting would be problematic but I wanted to know how it works and what makes this problem. Thanks to your comment, I realize how compiler treat memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```c++
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char arr2[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    char arr3[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    
    void* ptr_special2 = arr2 + 4;
    void* ptr_special3 = arr3 + 4;

    printf("address : %p: value : %d\n", ptr_special2, *(char**)ptr_special2);
    printf("address : %p: value : %d\n", ptr_special2, *(char**)ptr_special3);

    return 0;
}
```

output (may vary):

```
address : 0x7ffc5841755a: value : 50462981
address : 0x7ffc5841755a: value : 1074892805
```

Now try this:

```c++
    char arr2[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0 };
    char arr3[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,1,0,0 };
```

output:

```
address : 0x7fffecb291fc: value : 5
address : 0x7fffecb291fc: value : 261
```

Try to work out what's happening before reading the ...

## Explanation:

On my system, a "pointer to a pointer to a char" is 4 bytes long. So - when you take the address of the `5` in `arr2`, cast it to a `char**`, and dereference it - the system reads 4 bytes, starting at the `5`.

In `arr2`, those 4 bytes are `5 0 0 0`, which in a little-endian system is interpreted as 5.

In `arr3`, those 4 bytes are `5 1 0 0`, which in a little-endian system is interpreted as 5 + 256 = 261.

In your code, the three bytes after the `5` are unknown. You don't know what the compiler has placed there (if anything). You are reading beyond the end of the array because you are trying to read 4 bytes (or whatever `sizeof(char**)` is on your system) from an array that only has 1 valid byte at that address.

This is undefined behaviour, which means the standard allows literally anything to happen - but typically, you could expect:

1. "random garbage" bytes
2. The beginning of the next local variable
3. An access violation

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I do understand how it works. The casting before dereferencing tell the compiler how many bytes trying to read. It is really adorable example!!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, C has fairly lax rules when it comes to conversions between various pointer and integer types. If you add an explicit cast and thereby force a conversion, the code will *compile* in most cases. However, that doesn't necessarily mean that the code is correct. There are multiple forms of undefined behavior asociated with such wild conversions between different types. Alignment, type/address sizes, compatible types, pointer aliasing ([What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)) and so on. Lots of potential for bugs to consider.

There are *many* problems with this code. Specifically:

- `b = ptr;` This is invalid C. You cannot assign an integer to a pointer without an explicit cast. ["Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast" issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues). Yes "it compiles" but not without warnings. Code can compile with warnings and still be invalid C, see [What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277340).
- `b = (int)ptr;` would still be problematic because the pointer type may not fit inside an `int`. You should be using `uintptr_t` rather than `int` for such cases. As a consequence of using the wrong type, your examples bug out and do not print the address when I run them on my computer, but rather some gibberish like `0022FE400000000A` where it has managed to mess up pointer address + a value from the stack in the same 64 bit access. Which isn't guaranteed - it is undefined behavior - this was just what happened on one particular computer.
- `printf("%d\n", *(unsigned int*)b);` is valid but questionable since it changes signedness of the actual data from `int` to `unsigned int`, then immediately tells `printf` to convert back to `int` by using the `%d` specifier. Doesn't make any sense.
- Generally, you should `printf` pointers with `%p` or otherwise anything can happen.
- `*(void**)(b)` is needlessly complicated, why not write `(void*)b`.
- `*(char**)(b)` is questionable since it re-interprets the first byte of `a` into `char` which is potentially signed. You should be using `uint8_t` instead. More problematic yet is that the code states that the contents of `b` (that is: supposedly `&a`) is a `char**`, which you then convert to `char*`. It's an invalid pointer conversion since neither `char*` not `char**` are compatible types with `int*`. The compiler is free to do crazy things here.
- `*(char**)ptr_special` is simply using the wrong pointer type. You convert from array to `char*` to `void*`. Then claim that the `void*` is actually a `char**` and try to de-reference it, so you get gibberish. Correct code is `*(char*)ptr_special`.

Summary:

Do *not* do wild pointer conversions between unrelated types unless you are absolutely sure what you are doing. The compiler may let all manner of crap through but that doesn't mean that the code is correct.

Comment: I really appreciate your every point. I realized that there are many caution points when it comes to conversion. Actually, I have these curiosity while doing implementation malloc lab which has some weird (my opinion) conversions. By the way, thanks again. I have to be more careful and check again whenever the compiler works.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
printf("address : %p: value : %d\n", ptr_special, *(char**)ptr_special);
```

You're passing `char*` as an argument so the program will take 8 bytes(or 4, depending on compiler setting) from ptr_special.

The memory beginning at `arr2` will be something like this:

`01 02 03 04 05 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc`

It might be different from many reasons(optimization setting, etc) but important thing is that there are some values after `arr2`. When you use expression `*(char**)ptr_special`, the program will interpret that as `0xcccccccccccccc05`(or `0xcccccc05`) and pass to `printf` function.

Because you used `%d` as format specifier, function will print the value as 4 byte integer `0xcccccc05`, which is `-858993659`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I find it out after checking memory in visual studio debug mode. Thanks a lot !!!!