# Why should I use (void*) in second parameter of WriteProcessMemory() func?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, memory, cheat-engine

I am trying to create a game trainer for a game. I have found the needed memory addresses and now I want to write my values into that address.

For example: address of ammo is: 0x0E9AFD07

The `WriteProcessMemory()` function in the Windows API can do this.

My source:

```
int main(){
    DWORD pid;
    int address = 0x0E9AFD07;
    const int data = 20;
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0 , "Max Payne v1.05");
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd , &pid);
    HANDLE hndl = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS , false ,pid);
    WriteProcessMemory(hndl , &address , &data , 4 , NULL); 

    return 0;
}
```

But this code does not work!

If I should use `WriteProcessMemory` like below:

```
WriteProcessMemory(hndl , (void*)0x0E9AFD07 , &data , 4 , NULL);
```

then the second parameter of the function is `LPVOID` type and I read that `LPVOID` is a pointer to anything.

So, why I can't pass a pointer to `int` (address variable) for the second parameter?

And why should I use `(void*)`?

Comment: oh sorry . why we use (void*) before the address ?

Comment: Sorry about the multiple edits. But please clarify which language (C or C++). The use of `false` *suggests* C++ but that may be defined (as 0) in C. And the `OpenProcess` process takes a `BOOL` second parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your two code snippets are *not* equivalent; rather, they are asking the `WriteProcessMemory` function to write data to *different* locations.

In the second snippet, you pass `0x0E9AFD07` (as a `void*`), which tells the function to write the data to memory starting at the given address (the hex value passed).

However, in the first snippet, you are passing the address of the `int` variable (which just happens to contain the value `0x0E9AFD07`); this will instruct the function to write data to the location of that variable - thus, overwriting the `0x0E9AFD07` value that is there (or failing in the attempt to do so).

If you want to pass an address stored in a local variable, then you need to cast the *value* of that variable to a `void*` pointer, like this:

```c
int main(){
    DWORD pid;
    int address = 0x0E9AFD07;
    const int data = 20;
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0 , "Max Payne v1.05");
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd , &pid);
    HANDLE hndl = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS , false ,pid);
    // The "int" variable's VALUE is the target address, so cast/pass that...
    WriteProcessMemory(hndl , (void*)address , &data , 4 , NULL); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although it is a relatively common C extension, it *is* an extension for `int` to be converted to any pointer type without a cast.  Even with C compilers that provide such an extension, it typically depends on compile options whether such conversions will be performed.

Comment: "if using C, the compiler will implicitly cast the int to a void*" No, that is plain wrong. If you are using a conforming compiler, there will be a diagnostic message since you wrote invalid C. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues

Answer (score 2):

- > Why should I use (void*)

  Because that's what the manual tells you that the function expects. Specifically:

  > `lpBaseAddress`
  >
  > A pointer to the base address in the specified process to which data is written. Before data transfer occurs, the system verifies that all data in the base address and memory of the specified size is accessible for write access, and if it is not accessible, the function fails.
- For the same reason, you can't pass the address of your local variable in turn containing the address, because that's not what the function expects.
- `LPVOID` is just Windows gibberish for `void*`, they are identical types.
- In order to turn an integer address into a pointer type, you need to cast, because that's how C and C++ were designed. You can't assign an integer to a pointer, see ["Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast" issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues).
- Notably `0x0E9AFD07` is a misaligned address, so writing a 4 byte integer to that address is fishy.