# How can a void pointer hold data meant for non pointer variables?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, implicit-conversion, void-pointers

I was practicing with void pointers when this code successfully compiled:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    void *x = (void*) 576;
    int *y = x;
    printf("%d\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand this. How can the literal 576 be type-casted to a void pointer? Additionally, notice how in the printf() function call, the dereference operator is missing from y. And yet it prints the value 576. And when I add the dereference operator to y, nothing prints to the terminal.

After a bit of research, I found out that NULL is just the literal 0 type-casted to a void pointer. Can anything be type-casted to a void pointer? Is the code I posted up dangerous?

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior. Printing a pointer (i.e. `y`) using `%d` is just wrong. Pointers shall be printed using `%p` and the pointer must be casted to `(void*)`

Comment: Further you want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues

Comment: BTW: If you didn't get a warning for the posted code, it's time to check your compile command. Forinstance for  `gcc` at least use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wextra`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer of the type `void *` may be converted to a pointer of other object type.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
> object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a
> pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the
> original pointer.

As for this call

```
printf("%d\n", y);
```

then you are trying to output a pointer using the conversion specifier `%d` that is designed to output integers. As a result such a call invokes undefined behavior.

If you want to output a pointer you need to use conversion specifier `%p` as for example

```
printf("%p\n", ( void * )y);
```

If you want to output a pointer as an integer you need to include headers `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>` (the last header already contains the first header) and to write like

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

//...

printf( "%" PRIuPTR "\n", ( uintptr_t )y );
```